# Redirect dev subdomain to dev subdirectory in HSTS compatible way

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, subdirectory, hsts

I'm trying to redirect

`http://dev.example.com`
to
`https://www.example/dev`

using this code in my htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/dev/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!dev).*)$ /dev/$1 [NC,L]
```

A security evaluation company is complaining about the following:

> The HTTP site redirects users to a new URL in a way that cannot be secured with HTTPS and HSTS headers. This leaves users open to man-in-the-middle attackers who can redirect them to a fraudulent/ spoofed version of the intended site.

How should I do this? First redirect
`http://dev.example.com`  to `https://dev.example.com`
and then
`https://dev.example.com` to `https://www.example.com/dev`?

Comment: Are you actually wanting to implement HSTS at this stage? Or are you just wanting to make the redirects HSTS-compliant? To confirm, are you wanting to redirect _everything_ from `dev.example.com` to `www.example.com`? It's just that your directives do not currently do that.

Comment: @MrWhite I want to redirect everything from  dev.example.com to www.example.com/dev
and make them HSTS compliant. is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should first redirect
`http://dev.example.com`  to `https://dev.example.com`
and then
`https://dev.example.com` to `https://www.example.com/dev` as you say.  When you implement HSTS, HTTPS redirects have to do nothing other than change `http` to `https`.   Redirects for other purposes such as changing the subdomain to the subdirectory have to be done in separate redirects.

You can modify your `.htaccess` rules to do so pretty easily by removing `dev/` from your first rewrite rule and keeping the dev subdomain:

```sh
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://dev.example.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!dev).*)$ /dev/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Hi @stephen-ostermiller. thanks, this works well for the domain but not for internal pages. i.e it gives an 404 when trying to redirect http://dev.example.com/page to https://www.example.com/dev/page (this page loads fine when accessed directly)

Comment: I fixed it for you

Comment: have you tested it ? sorry, still same 404...

Comment: Make sure you are clearing your browser cache between tests. or test on the command line like: `curl --head http://dev.example.com`

Comment: Hi @stephen-ostermiller - its still not working. also tried from browsers that didn't have cache for this domain.

Comment: Can you either tell me the actual domain or test with `curl` and show the results?

Comment: hope this helps
https://prnt.sc/22sc9z0

Comment: `curl --head http://prnt.sc/
HTTP/1.1 520 Origin Error`  -- you have a problem in your cloudflare configuration.   It has nothing to do with your `.htaccess`.   The rules you started with and the rules that I gave you won't work with CloudFlare.   It usually handles the HTTPS termination for your domain.   For these rules to work you'll need to remove Cloudflare.   If you want to use cloudflare you'll have to work on its configuration rather than .htaccess configuration.

Comment: There is no `dev.` subdomain for that domain: `Could not resolve host: dev.prnt.sc`  Did you have a different subdomain that you were trying to use?

Comment: oh no, this link is the image with the curl result. simple open it and look inside.

Comment: I open it and don't see any screenshot.  Can you edit the screenshot into your question instead?

Comment: i had to remove some cookie lines to make it fit

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
date: Tue, 14 Dec 2021 07:46:10 GMT
location: https://www.example.com/developer
strict-transport-security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-content-type-options: nosniff
vary: User-Agent
edit: Set-Cookie (.*) "$1;HttpOnly;Secure"
Set-Cookie: incap_ses_7213_1995282=hOObf8qjFmVTONUTxLkZZMJLuGEAAAAA+/Qo4LewbvLeIqWih7I4JA==; path=/; Domain=.example.com
Set-Cookie: ___utmvmEBVusappB=iStEfPdECCp; path=/; Max-Age=900

Comment: Rather than adding details in comments, please [edit] your answer to add requested information. You can then comment saying that you have done so. Comments here may get hidden by "show more comments" or could be deleted without notice. Editing updates into your answer ensures that they don't get lost and that everybody who wants to use your answer sees them.

Comment: The only lines that are important are the first one and the `location:` line.     Was this a request for `http://example.com/developer`?

Comment: Thanks. when performing 
curl --head http://developer.example.com
i get  location: https://www.example.com/developer

Comment: That sounds like it works perfectly.

Comment: the issue starts with this curl --head http://developer.example.com/my-overview/
i get: 
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Comment: I see the problem, it needs an `[R=301]` in that rule.  Both the rules need it if you want them to redirect. I edited my answer.

Comment: i really appreciate your help. but that didnt help though.